# Reactor for electrical energy design base assumption inefficient?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

Im no physicist or engineer but as I observe our methods to obtain electrical energy I noticed a pattern where we cause a exothermic reaction, the resulting energy heats water, that turns into vapor, that moves a "paddle" and the paddle moves a magnet... basically...

That sounds rather inefficient to me... sounds like a lot of energy gets lost between the "explosion" and the turn of the magnet... What is the current view of the scientific community on this process? Besides "rotating a magnet", do we know of other ways to get electrons moving on ours power-lines that can reliably operate 24/7?

**Edit1:**
Added the "can reliably operate 24/7" part.

Comment: I actually find this question to be rude in the sense that it carries an unwritten assumption that the (multi-billion dollar a year) power industry has been going along *not thinking about what they are doing* for the last century. Really? There are R&D engineer who spend their entire careers working on a single aspect of this problem.

Comment: I don't read it as insulting - he states that it *seems* inefficient (which is more or less true), and explains why he thinks so (showing that he put some effort into thinking before asking, which many questions do not show), then asks about the consensus of the professional community.

Comment: I'll side more with @dmckee here - without looking at the efficiencies of any alternatives (say, thermoelectric generation directly from the heat) the steam-based electrical generators look bad. And, of course, we know other ways to generate power (e.g. solar) that do not need to rotate a magnet.  But to look at a huge installed base that operates reasonably well and merely question it?  Not much prior work there.

Comment: Understand that I think there are some worthy if basic elements here, but that the framing of the question in terms of "Here is may layman's opinion has anyone else noticed this?" is problematic. *Of course*, people have noticed that; smart people have spend decades and many millions of dollars nibbling away at it. Big fixed gas turbines used for power generation come closer than any other mad-made engines to realizing their theoretical Carnot efficiency.

Comment: Your question belongs into economics, not physics. Can one make (slightly) more efficient power plants? Yes. Is it worth it? No. And that is pretty much the end of the story as far as engineers are concerned because there is no engineering without money. The better question is anyway: How can we use the waste heat better? That's called co-generation and it has been used for many decades.